# SQL query for Rails 4 table reading one column but not the other correctly using .where

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to produce a result based on an if condition that uses the `&&` construction.

In my view, I need to do two things: 1) check to see if the current # of registered players exceeds the max specified by `max_players`; 2) Check and confirm that the user has not already registered.

If the query matches both conditions, I will return an error.

```
<% if Participation.where(game_id: params[:id]).count >= Game.first.max_players && Participation.where(user_id: current_user.id).exists?(false) %>
 <p>Sorry, it failed.</p>

<% else %>

<div class="button-wrap">
            <br>
            <a class="btn rad-button2 wwt flat vertical" <%= link_to "Reserve Spot", reservation_path(id: params[:id]) %> </a>  
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

Despite how both conditions are structured almost identically, the 2nd condition seems to be "true" (meaning, weirdly in this case, that it is false, and the `current_user.id` does not exist) at all times regardless of what is in the real table.

**Testing**

1. First thing I checked was to identify which condition was causing a problem. If I remove the 2nd condition and go to a game where the # of matching results with the same `game_id` in the table matches the params, it will show the error. So far, so good. However, if I use the second condition only on a game where the `current_user` has registered, it still defaults to the else condition.
2. Am I sure there are results that match both conditions? Let's say I am using the URL `http://localhost:3000/lobby?id=2`. Ok, I want to find matching results with the `id` of "4."

   ```
   Participation id: 4, user_id: 2, game_id: 2, ranking: 0, created_at: "2016-03-19 07:20:14", updated_at: "2016-03-19 07:20:14">, 
   Participation id: 30, user_id: 3, game_id: 2, ranking: 0, created_at: "2016-03-19 07:57:36", updated_at: "2016-03-19 07:57:36
   ```

As you can see, we have two `game_id` for our matching params. In my `Game` table, I specify that the max is 1 player for testing, so 2 > 1, and first condition passes (and the test with it alone is successful at producing error).

The second condition though -- when signed in as `user_id: 2` still fails to produce the error, yet it is using the same `where` strategy.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

**Edit 1 - Adding Participation Migration**

```
class CreateParticipations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :participations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :game, index: true
      t.integer :ranking, null: false, default: 0

      t.timestamps
     end
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) for `exists?` have this to say about what the argument to `exists?` mean:

> The argument can take six forms:
>
> - Integer - Finds the record with this primary key.
> - String - Finds the record with a primary key corresponding to this
>     string (such as '5').
> - Array - Finds the record that matches these find-style conditions
>     (such as ['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]).
> - Hash - Finds the record that matches these find-style conditions (such
>     as {name: 'David'}).
> - **false - Returns always false.**
> - No args - Returns false if the table is empty, true otherwise.

(emphasis mine). I'm not sure what you thought you were accomplishing by doing `exists?(false)`, but the method appears to be behaving as documented.

Answer (score 1):

House keeping suggestion, move this to a method:

```
<% if Participation.where(game_id: params[:id]).count >= Game.first.max_players && Participation.where(user_id: current_user.id).exists?(false) %>
```

in participation.rb:

```
def self.below_max_and_unregistered?(game_id)
   Participation.where(game_id: game_id).count >= Game.find(game_id).max_players && 
     !(Participation.where(user_id: current_user.id).exists?)
end
```

then if you view simply call

```
    <% if Participation.below_max_and_unregistered?(params[:id]) %>
```

In order to debug why your condition is failing...try separating them and running them each individually to see which is failing and resolve the underlying reason.